# A property of Lebesgue integrable function

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let f be a nonnegative integrable function on measureable space (X,v).
Then
      tv ({x: f (x)>t}) converges to 0, as t goes infinity.

I want to prove this statement. I got that v ({x: f (x)>t}) goes to zero as t goes infinity. But I cannot prove the full statement.

If tv ({x: f (x)>t}) goes to zero, 
g (t)v ({x: f (x)>t}) converges to zero whenever g (t)t}) converges to zero or not for g (t)>t.
I want to know significant difference of g (t) from t, not the form the constant times t.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: You probably mean $g( t)/t$, not $g( t)t$. Finally, the significance of $t$ is that $t \cdot 1_{f(x)>t} \leq |f|$. I leave it to you to find out why this is helpful.